# How to remove some string value in timestamp

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe column timestamp is string format 
2016-03-29 23:29:14 +0000. 
How can keep only 2016-03-29 23:29:14.?

Comment: [MCVE], please.

Comment: your_string.split('+')[0], although yes timgeb is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original timestamp column is of type string, then you can proceed as follows:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
                   timestamp
0  2016-03-29 23:29:14 +0000

In [3]: pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp).astype(str)
Out[3]: 
0    2016-03-29 23:29:14
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```